# expected_shape variable does not have any effect in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code segment, even though the initial values and `expected_shape` do not match, the code runs and gives output as `1.0`. Here is the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(0.0, expected_shape=(3,1))
b = tf.Variable(1.0)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(tf.add(W,b)))
```

Isn't it supposed to throw an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, it is advised to make use of [tf.get_variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) and avoid tf.Variable as much as possible.

Now coming to your question on why `expected_shape` is not having any effect, if you look into [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L278), it is mentioned as it is Deprecated and ignored. If you further look into the function of `_init_from_args`, the parameter of `expected_shape` is totally ignored and that value is not used for further processing.